# Cancel notification without using Notification Manager

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an application in which it receives the notification when fired from Backend. Now what I want to achieve is that the notification should disappear after 2 minutes if user has not clicked on it (even if my app is killed or background). I know that this can be achieved by using the Notification manager's `setTimeoutAfter()` but that will work only if am making my custom notification using Notifcation Manger.But i want to dismiss the Notification generated by System after 2 minutes.
Any kind of suggestion or help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that. The default system notification builder is pretty bare bones and will not handle it. The best you can do is set a delivery timeout so if the device was off it won't get the notification once it expires.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#when_to_use_platform_specific_keys (only works on Android and Web)